# Why don't need ram_payer for erase method in mulit_index class?

Tags: smart-contract, ram, multi-index

[mulit_index](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp) class has three methods ([emplace](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp#L1657), [modify](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp#L1764), [erase](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp#L2082)) to update a table.

`emplace` and `modify` methods need to select `ram_payer`. But `erase` method doesn't need to select it.

I think these methods need it because these change table.
So why don't need ram_payer for erase method in mulit_index class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `emplace` and `modify` methods need to know who is paying for the row that is being added/modified so that their accounts can be charged.  When you call `erase`, however, you aren't storing anything.  Instead, you are removing a row.  In this case, EOS already knows who paid for that row and simply refunds the RAM cost to that account when the data is erased.